# Help with Proof of theorem about Riemann Integrability Criteria

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

To prove the Riemann Integrability Criteria:

A bounded function $f$ on the interval [$a, b$] is Riemann integrable iff given an $\epsilon$ > 0 we may determine a positive number $\delta$ so that $\sum_P(sup f-inf f)\Delta x < \epsilon$ for all partitions P whose subintervals have length less than $\delta$.

the book starts with some statements I am not able to follow:

$Proof.$ If we assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable on the interval [$a,b$], then
given an $\epsilon> 0$ we have a $\delta > 0$ and a number A so that for any partition
of [$a,b$] whose subintervals have length less than $\delta$, every Riemann sum is
between $A-\epsilon/4$ and $A+\epsilon/4$. But then the absolute value of the difference
of any two Riemann sums is less than $\epsilon/2$, and $\sum_P(sup f -inf f)\Delta x < \epsilon$.

So my questions are:

Where does $\epsilon/4$ come from? Is this choice arbitrary? Can it be $\epsilon/10$ as well?

And then given this initial value, and following with the value of the absolute difference which makes sense, I dont't see then the last statement that goes from the absolute difference to the conclusion that the difference of the Upper and Lower Riemann sums has to be less than $\epsilon$, why not still $\epsilon/2$?

Comment: It comes from the author making something like $|x - y| \leq |x-z|+|z-y| \leq |x-a|+|a-z| + |z-b|+|b-y|$ and bounding each term by a quarter of epsilon. Yes, you can use $\epsilon/10$ or $2.34\epsilon,$ and _any_ fraction of $\epsilon$ will do (more generally, any function $\varphi(\epsilon) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$).

Comment: The $\epsilon/4$ is a style thing. The point of this is that the estimates you will use when starting with this $\epsilon/4$ will end with an inequality of the form $(\dots) < \epsilon$. But it is not important, because the $\epsilon$ is arbitrary anyway. This style thing is very common in textbooks because it results in clean arguments, but is really somewhat controversial because the origin of the actual function of $\epsilon$ you use generally appears *later* in the argument.

Comment: As for this extra fudge factor, that is accounting for the possibility that the sup and/or inf might not be attained; for an example where that happens, look at $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1-1/n & x=1/n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ on the leftmost subinterval.